# What causes Windows 10 to throttle the CPU to ~1 GHz at random intervals?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, throttling

I've been getting this bug for a while now, where once in a while the PC becomes unbearably slow because the CPU is being throttled to about 1 GHz at most.
It isn't a frequent issue; this will happen about once every few months.

I'm aware that this is an issue sometimes seen in laptops with power managing functions enabled that throttle CPU performance when battery is low or when temperatures are high, though this also happens on desktops.

The often recommended fix is to temporarily change the `Minimum processor state` in `Power Plan Settings` from `100%` to `99%` and back to `100%` again, or reset the power plan(which likely also changes this setting).
[See this answer for reference](https://superuser.com/questions/1024497/cpu-and-memory-running-well-below-set-clock-speed).

However, this only seems a symptomatic fix; the issue will not stop and will still occur at random intervals.

I've checked temperatures and those're all sitting comfortably around 60°C. The PC and it's components are about three months old. I've also had this issue on my previous desktop, strangely enough, never on any laptops I've had though. This desktop had an Intel i7 920 (2008), so that might mean this issue isn't related to the CPU manufacturer.

**My question is the following:**
1. What causes this issue? Is it a bug or a feature I don't understand?
2. Is there a way to *permanently* disable this bug or 'feature'?

Please note: this is likely **not** related to overheating or impending loss of power.

**Hardware info and Power Plan settings:**

```
-- Hardware Info --
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700x  
GPU: MSI RTX 2080    
32 GB RAM  
1TB SSD + 3TB HDD  
Windows 10 Home edition; last update was yesterday.
Power supply is rated 700W. 

-- Power plan settings: --
Hard drive  
    Turn off hard drive after: Never  

Internet Explorer  
    JavaScript Timer Frequency: Maximum performance  

Desktop Background settings  
    Slideshow: Available  

Wireless Adapter Settings  
    Energy saving mode: Maximum performance  

Sleep  
    Sleep after: Never  
    Hibernate after: Never  
    Allow wake-up timers: Disabled  

  USB Settings  
    USB Selective suspend setting: Disabled  

Power buttons and lid  
    Power button action: Shut down  

PCI Express  
    Link State Power Management: Disabled  

Processor power management  
    Minimum processor state: 100%  
    System cooling policy: Active  
    Maximum processor state: 100%:  

Display  
    Turn off display after: Never
```